# Notifying native music player that a music file is added to storage

Tags: android

How to notify the android that a mp3 file is added to the storage and let it display the file inside the music app? I am converting a video to audio, but the file is not displaying in the music player. Now, I moved the file from one folder to another using File Manager. Now the music player is displaying the file. Shall I notify the android that a media file is added so that the music player can display it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're looking for `Media ScannerConnection Class`. Just have a look in the developer site here:

[**MediaScannerConnection**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html)

Comment: :)))))))))))))))))))))